# groovy variable function

Tags: groovy, dynamic-languages

I'm not even sure about how to title this qn. But, hope there is an easy way to do it in dynamic language like groovy.

say I have a class Service, where I delegate the business logic. the methods in it are 
`funA(), funB()... funX()`.

Now I have a controller class, where I call the service closure, which can be invoked like service.funA() . Now based on a variable (which can have values `A, B ... X`), I need to cal the  correct service closure. Basically to avoid writing lot of if conditional statements.   Something like `service."fun+var"()` would do. I'm not sure whether it is possible to substitute variable in closure (function)name. or any way by passing function (name) as a parameter...not sure

I think PHP has a similar feature   http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

thanks for any pointer..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. This should do what you want:

```
service."fun${var}"()
```

The correct title is [dynamic method invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy).